# Use boost::tokenizer with boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

I'm using `boost::tokenizer` to read a CSV-like file. I'm storing the the tokens in a `std::vector`. It works well, but I want to store only a `boost::iterator` for each token.

I tried:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

typedef std::string::const_iterator string_iter;
typedef boost::iterator_range<string_iter> string_view;

int main(){
    std::string line;

    std::vector<string_view> contents;

    boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>, string_iter, string_view> tok(line.begin(), line.end());
    contents.assing(tok.begin(), tok.end());
}
```

But it fails to compile:

> /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool
>   boost::escaped_list_separator::operator()(InputIterator&, InputIterator, Token&) [with
>   InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Token =
>   boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; Char = char; Traits =
>   std::char_traits]’: /usr/include/boost/token_iterator.hpp:70:11:
>   required from ‘void boost::token_iterator::initialize() [with TokenizerFunc =
>   boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’
>   /usr/include/boost/token_iterator.hpp:77:63:   required from
>   ‘boost::token_iterator::token_iterator(TokenizerFunc, Iterator, Iterator) [with
>   TokenizerFunc = boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’ /usr/include/boost/tokenizer.hpp:86:53: 
>   required from ‘boost::tokenizer::iter
>   boost::tokenizer::begin() const [with
>   TokenizerFunc = boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; boost::tokenizer::iter =
>   boost::token_iterator,
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > > >]’
>   /home/wichtounet/dev/gooda-to-afdo-converter/src/gooda_reader.cpp:58:37:
>   required from here /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:187:16:
>   error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += (&
>   next)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >()’ /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:193:11: error: no match for
>   ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += (&
>   next)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >()’ /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void
>   boost::escaped_list_separator::do_escape(iterator&,
>   iterator, Token&) [with iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Token =
>   boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; Char = char; Traits =
>   std::char_traits]’:
>   /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:176:11:   required from ‘bool
>   boost::escaped_list_separator::operator()(InputIterator&, InputIterator, Token&) [with
>   InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Token =
>   boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; Char = char; Traits =
>   std::char_traits]’ /usr/include/boost/token_iterator.hpp:70:11: 
>   required from ‘void boost::token_iterator::initialize() [with TokenizerFunc =
>   boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’
>   /usr/include/boost/token_iterator.hpp:77:63:   required from
>   ‘boost::token_iterator::token_iterator(TokenizerFunc, Iterator, Iterator) [with
>   TokenizerFunc = boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’ /usr/include/boost/tokenizer.hpp:86:53: 
>   required from ‘boost::tokenizer::iter
>   boost::tokenizer::begin() const [with
>   TokenizerFunc = boost::escaped_list_separator; Iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; Type = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; boost::tokenizer::iter =
>   boost::token_iterator,
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > > >]’
>   /home/wichtounet/dev/gooda-to-afdo-converter/src/gooda_reader.cpp:58:37:
>   required from here /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:130:9:
>   error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += '\012'’
>   /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:134:9: error: no match for
>   ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += (&
>   next)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >()’ /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:138:9: error: no match for
>   ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += (&
>   next)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >()’ /usr/include/boost/token_functions.hpp:142:9: error: no match for
>   ‘operator+=’ in ‘tok += (&
>   next)->__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator,
>   _Container>::operator* >()’

I also simply tried to compute the two iterators by myself using the `boost::token_iterator`, but I haven't been successful so far.

Is there a solution to get only the iterator range of each token instead of the string in order to save some performances ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work. The `tokenizer` expects a type (the third template argument) which can be appended with the results of the tokenizer function. Specifically, it must provide the operator `+= ( tokenizer<...>::iterator::value_type )`. The [code snippet](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f65fedf93f4605f1504d729c1ddeb536) below should take you a step further, though I am not sure if it's worth the effort...

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

typedef std::string::const_iterator string_iter;
typedef boost::iterator_range<string_iter> string_view;

// a constant size character buffer, skips anything beyond CSize...
template< std::size_t CSize >
class assignable_view {
   std::size_t m_size;
   char m_buffer[CSize];

   friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& p_out, assignable_view const & p_view)
   {
      if (p_view.m_size > 0u) {
         std::copy(p_view.m_buffer, p_view.m_buffer + p_view.m_size, std::ostream_iterator<char>(p_out));
      }
      return p_out;
   }

public:
   template <class TIter>
   void operator += (TIter p_input) 
   {
      if (m_size < CSize) {
         m_buffer[m_size++] = p_input;
      }   
   }   
   assignable_view() 
      : m_size(0u) {}
};

int main(){
    std::string line
        = "Field 1,\"putting quotes around fields, allows commas\",Field 3";

    std::vector<string_view> contents;

    boost::tokenizer<
       boost::escaped_list_separator<char>, 
       string_iter, 
       assignable_view<11>    
    > tok(line.begin(), line.end());

    for (auto const & t_s : tok) {
       std::cout << t_s << std::endl;
    }
    //contents.assing(tok.begin(), tok.end());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah! You'd need an include:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator string_iter;
    typedef boost::iterator_range<string_iter> string_view;

    boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>, string_iter, string_view> tok(line.begin(), line.end());
}
```

[compiles fine](http://ideone.com/JzKGUK)

Comment: Ok, my bad :( My example was real bad. The problem comes only when the tokenizer is iterated. I updated my sample. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. But just from the description I'm thinking, that keeping the iterators might be dangerous anyway.

Comment: As long as I keep the original string along the iterators, it should not cause any problem. I was already doing that with boost::split before.

Comment: An interesting riddle. Obviously, the iterator range doesn't offer the += operator. When looking at the types, I can't see why it should. Perhaps, the iterator_range should be rethought

Comment: Have you alternatively tried the string algo or regex? :) Perhaps that might resolve the question: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3997 [(or that)](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Re-lexical-cast-Fast-conversion-from-boost-iterator-range-lt-std-string-iterator-gt-td4100475.html)